# Change from using id to class to open a modal from any of 6 images

Tags: javascript, css, class, modal-dialog

I have 6 different images in a row that are randomly picked from an array of objects containing a thumbnail and a hi res image (the same as the thumbnail). I want to be able to click any of the thumbnails and open a modal with a full screen hi res image. Since I am using the id, it only works with the first of six images. When I try to change it to class it is not working. I want to change it to class because it is my understanding that it will work with all six images. There are 96 images in my array, 48 thumbnails, and 48 hi res images. I will provide an abridged sample of this array. I will also provide the HTML, JavaScript, and the CSS (all abridged).

I've tried using .avengerpic and avengerpic (the name of the class) but neither are working. I want to display 6 thumbnails in a row, and be able to click on any of them and open up a modal with the larger hi res image.

```js
        let picArray = [
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_1.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_1.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_2.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_2.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_3.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_3.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_4.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_4.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_5.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_5.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_6.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_6.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_7.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_7.jpg"}]

    let moviePics = function() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.avengerPic').forEach(function(e) {
        const randomPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * picArray.length));
        e.src = picArray[randomPic].thumbnail;
      });
    }

    moviePics();

    let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    let img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    let modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    let img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    let modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pics">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <div class="photosTitle">
                        <h3>Photos</h3>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <i class="arrowleft" onclick="moviePics()"></i>

                    <img class="avengerPic" id="myImg" src="https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_5.jpg" width="99" height="99">
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                        <div id="caption"></div>
                    </div>

                    <img class="avengerPic" id="myImg" src="https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_5.jpg" width="99" height="99">
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                        <div id="caption"></div>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: baseline;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 5px 15px;
    }

    .pics img {
      padding: 2px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed; /* doesn't move */
      z-index: 1; /* on top */
      padding-top: 50px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
      /* background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); */
    }

    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      /* position: fixed; */
      display: block;
      width: 85%;
      max-width: 1000;
      max-height: 520;
    }

    .caption {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ccc;
      padding: 10px 0;
      height: 150px;
    }

    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
      font-size: 40px;
      /* font-weight: bold; */
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let moviePics = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.avengerPic').forEach(function(e) {
        const randomPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * picArray.length));
        e.src = picArray[randomPic].thumbnail;
    });
}

moviePics();


let imgs= document.querySelectorAll(".avengerPic");    
let closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
    imgs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let thumbSrc = this.src;
        let bigImgSrc;
        for(var j=0; j<picArray.length; j++){
           if (thumbSrc == picArray[j].thumbnail){
               bigImgSrc = picArray[j].image
           }
        }    
        this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        this.nextElementSibling.children[1].src = bigImgSrc;
        this.nextElementSibling.children[2].innerHTML = this.alt;
     })
 }
for (var i=0; i<closeBtns.length; i++){
    closeBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.parentElement.style.display = "none";    
    })
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you so much! I'm making a module similar to one found on IMDb, a mediastrip is what they call it. I learned a great deal from this code you shared and am going to look it over and study it closely to further my understanding of how to achieve this!